# Java HTTP Basic Authenication Explained

Tags: java, http, authentication

Can someone please explain how exactly the user credentials are passed to the server in the below code...

```
        URL urlObj = new URL("https://javaguy.com");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection(); conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/xml");

        String userPassword = username + ":" + password;
        byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(userPassword.getBytes());
        String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
```

Is it part of the HTTP header? Just curious.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You've answered your own question, but yes.  The "Authorization" is part of the header.

You can read more about basic authentication on the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

Then the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) isn't super clear, but the setRequestProperty should add the new property to the request header.

As a side note, I would urge you to consider using a library like [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) if you're planning on doing any http requests in a production system.  Working directly with URL and URLConnection directly can be tricky.  HttpClient isn't super easy to work with either, but it is easier then URL/URLConnection.

There are two HttpClient libraries, make sure you're working with version 4 (which is the latest version at the time of this post) and not version 3.